# After JavaScript alert value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I am doing JavaScript alert after that value is been null from the input text. But I want that after the JavaScript alert value should be available in the input text.

Here is my code

```
<script>

        function validateform() {

            var email = $('#txt_emailID').val();
            if (email == null || email == "") {
                alert("Email Should Be Complusory");
                return false;
            }
            var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
            var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.length) {
                alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address...!!!");
                                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>

<label for="fname">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_name" name="txt_name" placeholder="Your Name.." />

        <label for="lname">EmailID</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_emailID" name="email" placeholder="Your EmailID.." />

        <label for="lname">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_subject" name="txt_subject" placeholder="Your Subject.." />

        <input type="submit" id="submit_mail" value="Send" />

        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(document).on("click", "#submit_mail", function () {
                    if (validateform() == false) {
                        document.getElementById("txt_name").value = $('#txt_name').val();
                        document.getElementById("txt_subject").value = $('#txt_subject').val();

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                });
            });
```

I don't know where I am getting a problem.

Comment: That happens because of you have used button type as submit and you have bind click event of that button so that on click of that form will submit. If form is submitted you values will be null

Comment: please don't make a `click` event on the submit button. make a `submit` event on the form (if there is one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prevent default action of submit button which is to submit the form.

Use [`Event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
function validateform() {
  var email = $('#txt_emailID').val();
  if (email == null || email == "") {
    alert("Email Should Be Complusory");
    return false;
  }
  var atposition = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotposition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atposition < 1 || dotposition < atposition + 2 || dotposition + 2 >= email.length) {
    alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address...!!!");
    return false;
  }
}
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#submit_mail", function(e) {
    if (validateform() == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("txt_name").value = $('#txt_name').val();
      document.getElementById("txt_subject").value = $('#txt_subject').val();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="fname">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="txt_name" name="txt_name" placeholder="Your Name.." />

<label for="lname">EmailID</label>
<input type="text" id="txt_emailID" name="email" placeholder="Your EmailID.." />

<label for="lname">Subject</label>
<input type="text" id="txt_subject" name="txt_subject" placeholder="Your Subject.." />

<input type="submit" id="submit_mail" value="Send" />
```

Comment: yup got it. Thank You. :)